# Google Chart Tools populated from database

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I've made a site using c# and asp.net MVC using an EF code first approach. I want to populate a Google chart with data from my sql database. I watched a pluralsight video explaining this, however it was using PHP and I need to use c#. I have a database table Event which has two properties one to represent the total tickets available and another to represent the number still available.
I want to make a chart showing the total available and the number left.

This is my view so far

```
@model Site.Models.Event

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<head>  
 <script type="text/javascript"   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
 <title> Title </title>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var chart, data;

        var serverData = $.ajax({
            url: 'data.json',
            type: 'json',
            context: document.getElementById('chart'),
            success: function (serverData) {
                data = new google.visualization.DataTable(serverData);
                chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(this);
                chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });
            }
        });
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart" style="height: 500px; width: 900px;"></div>
</body>
```

If anyone can help me with the code I need to write in the controller to return the data from the database, which I assume needs to be a JSON result, and how to use this I would really appreciate it.